# Can I stream an MP4 video of duration > 10 minutes on iOS

Tags: ios, video, http-live-streaming

I'm building an app that is playing different streaming videos. The file that I'm playing in my `AVPlayer` object is an MP4 file.
Reading through the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/) I just noticed that the rule 2.5.7 says:

> Video streaming content over a cellular network longer than 10 minutes must use HTTP Live Streaming and include a baseline 192 kbps HTTP Live stream.

What does this mean exactly? Can I stream an MP4 video which is longer than 10 minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your MP4 video is less than 10 minutes then presumably you can just put it on a server somewhere and have the player download the file (progressive download) - you don't need to use a streaming protocol like HLS. However, if your video *is* more than 10 minutes then you *must* use HLS. This means segmenting your video into chunks and creating a playlist for them. You can do this with Apple's streaming tools - such as `mediafilesegmenter` - or you can use [ffmpeg to segment your videos](http://hlsbook.net/segmenting-video-with-ffmpeg/).

That guideline is for cellular networks *only*, so it doesn't apply if the user is connected via wifi. Take a look at Apple's [recommendations](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2224/_index.html) for encoding your video(s) for HLS.

Comment: My videos are definitely longer than 10 minutes. So I could convert all my videos with ffmpeg and how will I host them then? Do I need a specific html page with a video tag?

Comment: Just deploy the files to a web server like you would do with a web page or a CSS file. You can use the HTML5 video tag, setting the source of the video to the URL of the playlist. I believe Safari is still the only (desktop) browser to support HLS natively. For other browsers, you'll have to use a plugin like hls.js or something equivalent.

Comment: In your original question you mentioned that you are using AVPlayer to play your video. In that case, you could create an instance of NSURL with the URL of the playlist and then pass that to the playerWithURL: method of AVPlayer.

Comment: Thanks, I just bought the book and it seems like a nice resource to learn more about HLS.

Answer (score 0):

It explicitly says you CAN play a video longer than 10 minutes. However, the guidelines say your app will be rejected if it doesn't meet the requirements stated.

Admittedly I've never attempted a 10 minute video playback, but from the documentation it seems to imply your media must allow 192 kbps playback (presumably for cellular data plans) and also must conform to the HTTP Live Stream protocol.

Here is the technical documentation Apple provides on HTTP Live streaming
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2224/_index.html

Best of luck! Please let me know if I can help with anything more specific :)